# How do I check in a piece of of data is in a specific column of a dataset (python)?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dataset

I have a two dimensional array, and want to check if a specific number is in a certain column.
For example, if I have something like
list = [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
I want it to tell me if there is a 3 in the first part of the list.

I tried to do
if 3 in list['Number"]:

where one of the columns in the dataset is the Number, but it just says "syntax error"

Comment: Why do you try to get list['Number']?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with a sample of your input data and a reproducible amount of code. In this example, there is no "number" in the data provided, you mix single and double quotes, and your variable name `list` shadows the built-in `list` type

Comment: It may be `3 in list['Number'].values`. If you post a working example, we can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

- `row=0` means you want to search in the first row
- `target=3` is the target that you want search for
- `column=0` means you want to search in the first column (i make it as comment because you want to search in the whole first row)

i suggest you to check [this](https://www.scaler.com/topics/2d-array-in-python/) it will help you to know more about what is row and column in array

```
arr = [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
row = 0
target = 3
# column = 0

if any(row[column] == target for row in arr):
    print(f"{target} found in column {column}")
else:
    print(f"{target} not found in column {column}")
```